# Quarter of year power bi

Tags: powerbi, m

i am trying to get quarter from date ..

i tried this query

```
let
    Source = "",
    Custom1 = Source,
    Custom2 = Calendar2,
    Custom3 = let
    Source = List.Dates(#date(1996, 1, 1), 500, #duration(1, 0, 0, 0)),#"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Converted to Table",{{"Column1", "Date"}}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed Columns",{{"Date", type date}}),StartDate = #date(2016, 1, 1),
    Today = DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow()),
    Length = Duration.Days(Today - StartDate),
    Custom1 = #"Changed Type",
    #"Inserted Year" = Table.AddColumn(Custom1, "Fin Year", each Date.Year([Date]+#duration(184,0,0,0)), Int64.Type),
    #"Inserted Month Name" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Year", "Month Name", each Date.MonthName([Date]), type text),
    #"Inserted Day Name" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Month Name", "Day Name", each Date.DayOfWeekName([Date]), type text),
    #"Inserted Quarter of Year"= Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Quarter of Year","Quarter of Year",each Date.QuarterOfYear([Date]),Int64.Type),
    #"Inserted Month" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Day Name", "Fin Month", each if Date.Month([Date]) >=7 then Date.Month([Date])-6 else Date.Month([Date])+6  , Int64.Type),
    #"Inserted Day of Week" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Month", "Day of Week", each Date.DayOfWeek([Date])+1, Int64.Type),
    #"Inserted First Characters" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Day of Week", "MMM", each Text.Start([Month Name], 3), type text),
    #"Inserted First Characters1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted First Characters", "DDD", each Text.Start([Day Name], 3), type text),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Inserted First Characters1",{"Date", "Fin Year", "Month Name", "MMM", "Fin Month", "Day Name", "DDD", "Day of Week"}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Reordered Columns", "YYMM", each ([Fin Year]-2000)*100 + [Fin Month]),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom",{{"YYMM", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type1", "MonthID", each (Date.Year([Date]) - Date.Year(StartDate))*12 + Date.Month([Date])),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom1",{{"MonthID", Int64.Type}})

in
    #"Changed Type2"
in
    Custom3
```

quarter line from above code

```
#"Inserted Quarter of Year"= Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Quarter of Year","Quarter of Year",each Date.QuarterOfYear([Date]),Int64.Type),
```

when i tried this shows an error

Expression.Error: The name 'Inserted Quarter of Year' wasn't recognized. Make sure it's spelled correctly.

and also there is probelm when  i rename "Fin Month " to only "Month" this shows also an error

how to resolve this

Comment: Apologies for misreading, have deleted my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the syntax wrong and self referring to the column that you are trying to create, you need to reference the previous step.

Inserted Quarter of Year

```
#"Inserted Quarter of Year"= Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Quarter of Year","Quarter of Year",each Date.QuarterOfYear([Date]),Int64.Type),
```

should be:

```
#"Inserted Quarter of Year"= Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Day Name", "Quarter of Year",each Date.QuarterOfYear([Date]),Int64.Type)
```

[image]

Hope that helps